# How to disable the button after first click and i want the button click functionality after the day

Tags: angular, angular6

I want to create a button which will disable after clicks and enable next day, that is button will enable for single click for single day.

User will come to office and click button after clicking button gets disable and it only enable next day only.

Comment: Are you using Angular only? Do you have any backend or database? If don't, you need to use cookie which is not an effective way. Because, users can click with another browser or they can reclick after clearing cookies.

Comment: may it's possible using local storage or not

Comment: typically if you'd like to ask a question and get high quality / fast answers, you should include some code showing what you've tried and specifically where you're getting stuck.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this.  One is in your ts file, you can add a HostListener

```js
export class SampleComponent implements OnInit {
    @HostListener('window: click', ['$event'])
    onClick(ev) {
        const element = ev.target;
        if (element.classList.contains('classImLookingFor'){
            element.style.pointerEvents = 'none'
            // or if it's a button
            element.disabled = true;
        }

    }

    ...
}
```

You can also put in your template `<button [disabled]='current.date === date'>Date</button>`

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this recently using local storage and moment.js library for use with a modal and ngx-bootstrap. I think this could easily be translated to a button. In my scenario I only wanted the modal to show if the user had seen it and clicked accept over 9 hours ago. Using local storage is somewhat limiting in that if the user were to clear their browser data, they would also clear the local storage and the modal will appear again. In my case this doesn't really matter, but something to consider in your instance.

Sample code:

```
import { ModalDirective } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
export class LoginBannerComponent implements OnInit {

constructor() {}

ngOnInit() {
    const lastBannerShow = localStorage.getItem('lastBannerShow');
    const lastBannerShowMoment = lastBannerShow ? moment(lastBannerShow) : moment('1900-01-01');
    const now = moment();

    if (now.diff(lastBannerShowMoment, 'seconds') > 30) {
        this.isModalShown = true;
        localStorage.setItem('lastBannerShow', moment().format());
    } else {
        this.isModalShown = false;
    }
}

@ViewChild('autoShownModal', { static: false })
autoShownModal: ModalDirective;
isModalShown = false;

showModal(): void {
    this.isModalShown = true;
}

hideModal(): void {
    this.autoShownModal.hide();
}

onHidden(): void {
    this.isModalShown = false;
}
accept(): void {
    this.autoShownModal.hide();
}

reject(): void {
    this.isChildModalShown = true;
    this.isModalShown = false;

}
```

And in my HTML Template:

```
<div #autoShownModal="bs-modal"
 (onHidden)="onHidden()"
 *ngIf="isModalShown"
 [config]="{ show: true, animated: true, backdrop: true, ignoreBackdropClick: true }"
 aria-labelledby="dialog-auto-name"
 bsModal
 class="fade modal"
 role="dialog"
 tabindex="-1">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body text-white"
             style="background-color: #0072CE">
            <p class="font-weight-bold h4 text-capitalize text-center">MODAL CONTENT HERE</p>
            <div class="modal-footer text-white">
                <button (click)="accept()"
                        class="btn btn-success mr-auto"
                        type="button">
                    Accept
                </button>
                <button (click)="reject()"
                        class="btn btn-danger"
                        type="button">
                    Reject
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Look over what's in my ngOnInit section, and see if you can't replicate that local storage functionality and moment.js date comparison with an ngIf tag in your template. And instead of having the "banner show", you could use button, and have that button disabled or enabled based on the results of the logic in ngOnInit.